Spring Boot + Apache Camel+ IBM MQ Integration accessing un configured queue resulting in the warning
In Spring boot apache camel with IBM MQ integration apart from the configured queue with application another queue which is irrelevant is trying to access resulting in warning
Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.springframework.jms.JmsSecurityException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'QUEUE_NAME'.; nested
 exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.springframework.jms.JmsSecurityException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'QUEUE_NAME'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM 
MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').

why this warning is throw as the queue not even configured with application

You will need to look in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG to see the cause of that error.  Does the actual queue name start with SYSTEM?

IBM MQ will report MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED (2035) in preference to MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME (2085) which it sounds like you expected?
It does this so that an unauthorised user does not learn anything about the queue manager. In other words, learning that a queue is not defined tells you something about the system that you were not privileged enough to learn.
